# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I'm getting this error when I click to enter a certain layout of my application

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class

```
2020-08-16 14:45:27.960 22621-22621/com.deventretenimento.ganharassistindo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.deventretenimento.ganharassistindo, PID: 22621
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.deventretenimento.ganharassistindo/com.deventretenimento.ganharassistindo.Redeem}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3282)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1970)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7156)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class <unknown>
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:686)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:759)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:827)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:902)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:905)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:554)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:461)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:383)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.deventretenimento.ganharassistindo.Redeem.onCreate(Redeem.java:40)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7335)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7326)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1275)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3282)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1970)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7156)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.deventretenimento.ganharassistindo:drawable/backreedem with resource ID #0x7f08008f
2020-08-16 14:45:27.964 22621-22621/com.deventretenimento.ganharassistindo E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/backreedem.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f08008f
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:898)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:677)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:912)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:955)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:930)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5444)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:660)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:248)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:244)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:240)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:686)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:759)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:827)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:902)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:905)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:554)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:461)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:383)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.deventretenimento.ganharassistindo.Redeem.onCreate(Redeem.java:40)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7335)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7326)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1275)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3282)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1970)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7156)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
     Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #7<gradient> tag requires 'gradientRadius' attribute with radial type
        at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.updateGradientDrawableGradient(GradientDrawable.java:1661)
        at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.inflateChildElements(GradientDrawable.java:1423)
        at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.inflate(GradientDrawable.java:1244)
        at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:146)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1359)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1318)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:879)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:677) 
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:912) 
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:955) 
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:930) 
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5444) 
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:660) 
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:248) 
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:244) 
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:240) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:686) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:759) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:827) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:902) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:863) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:905) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:863) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:554) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:461) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:383) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170) 
        at com.deventretenimento.ganharassistindo.Redeem.onCreate(Redeem.java:40) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7335) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7326) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1275) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3119) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3282) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1970) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7156) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

this one is the layout I'm trying to enter and it gives this error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#EEF8FF"
    tools:context="com.deventretenimento.ganharassistindo.RedeemPayTm">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativecoinbalance"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="112dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/backreedem">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewCoins"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
                android:fontFamily="@font/font"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="45sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
                android:fontFamily="@font/font"
                android:text="MEU SALDO:"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="33dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"

                android:background="@drawable/back1"
                android:padding="21dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/coinmain" />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/backbutton2"
        android:padding="15dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/arrowback"
        android:contentDescription="TODO" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="88dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="GANHAR ASSISTINDO"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/payTmmobile"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.EditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:maxLength="9"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:text="0"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:fontFamily="@font/font"
        android:textColor="#434D74"
        android:textSize="100sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Checkout"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/font"

        android:layout_below="@+id/relative"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Quantas moedas você deseja transformar em dinheiro?"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:textColor="#3E425D"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/payTmmobile"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="69dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:fontFamily="@font/font"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back1now"
        android:onClick="payTm"
        android:text="CONTINUAR"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Checkout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:fontFamily="@font/font"

        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:fontFamily="@font/font"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:text="Você deve ter 500 000 moedas."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It is having difficulty finding `@drawable/backreedem`. Is there anything unusual about this resource?

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry, I do not understand

Comment: Your error is `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.deventretenimento.ganharassistindo:drawable/backreedem with resource ID #0x7f08008f`. So, for some reason, Android is not able to load that resource. What is that resource? What version of Android are you running on?

Comment: I just discovered, this drawable has a gradient style, it was "radial" I changed to "linear" and now it worked well

Comment: It also says `<gradient> tag requires 'gradientRadius' attribute with radial type`. If you use `radial` gradient you also need to set `gradientRadius`.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the drawable resource and run the app.If it still shows error than it must be sonething in your java code

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are using a library that is not optimized for the above Android. Display your library list.

For example, the library operates below its older versions Does not work on Android Api Down

```
   implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
```

Your code uses the library above. Use the update version to fix your problem

```
  android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title
```

new version in gradle

```
implementation 'io.github.inflationx:calligraphy3:3.1.1'
implementation 'io.github.inflationx:viewpump:2.0.3'
```

in Activity

```
    @Override
protected void attachBaseContext( Context newBase ) {
    super.attachBaseContext( ViewPumpContextWrapper.wrap( newBase ) );
}
```

in style

```
<style name="TextAppearance.FontPath" parent="android:TextAppearance">
<!-- Custom Attr-->
<item name="fontPath">fonts/RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf</item>
```

in xml

```
<TextView
android:text="@string/hello_world"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.FontPath"/>
```